# im trying to bypass the submit button above a hcaptcha, and it doesn't work

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i am trying to acess a second website that is given after i input an acess key, answer the capctha  and click on the "continuar".
[before clicking the submit "continuar" (i censored the key on the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njR4u.png)

i am new to using selenium, and this is my code

```py
#import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import getpass
import keyboard


siteGOV = "https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaRecaptcha.aspx?tipoConsulta=resumo&tipoConteudo=7PhJ+gAVw2g%3d"#http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaRecaptcha.aspx?tipoConsulta=resumo&tipoConteudo=7PhJ+gAVw2g="



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension("Buster-Captcha-Solver-for-Humans.crx")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
browser_driver = webdriver.ChromeService()
pageToScrap = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) #da o driver usado para pesquisa na net
pageToScrap.get(siteGOV) #site acessado


acessKey = "" 


possiveisAlvos = pageToScrap.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,  "input")

time.sleep(5)


for _i in possiveisAlvos:
    if _i.accessible_name == "Chave de Acesso da NF-e":
        _i.send_keys(acessKey)
        print("got it")




_l= True
while True:
    if _l:
        print("enter input when finishid the captcha")
    
    _l = False
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        break

for element in possiveisAlvos:
    if element.get_attribute("value") == "Continuar": #ACHEI O BOTAO DE CONTINUAR
        print(element)
        element.click()
        break

time.sleep(15)
pageToScrap.quit()
```

and everytime my code clicks on the "continuar", the page loads and show this [after clicking the submit (censored key)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj8bd.png)

[this is the html part that match with the submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avXgw.png)

i have found that the "onclick" is an event that occurs when i click in that element and call a function, searching for the function i found this
[the part of the code that is called onclick event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHRn9.png)

what should i do????

i swear i have finished the captcha myself, but even doing it carefully this error show.

Comment: What you should do is go find out if there is an official API to fetch this information.  They are actively trying to block the kind of scraping you are doing, in order to protect their information.

Comment: Well, you didn't solve the captcha, just as the error message tells you. As the captcha requirement is added there by the maintainers of the page exactly to deny the ability to scrape or remote-control the page with tools such as selenium, you should check with them if there is some other way you can (legitimately) access the required information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try to solve the captcha first and, once it is solved, then click on submit. You are trying to submit an unsolved captcha, which will obviously throw an error.

The thing is, you will probably face some problems when trying to solve the captcha. To solve that, you will have to either:

1. Use an official API: yes, they have an official API to do exactly what you want without the need of web scraping. Read [here](https://www.gov.br/pt-br/servicos/obter-solucao-de-consulta-de-dados-de-nota-fiscal-eletronica-nfe) and [here](https://www.loja.serpro.gov.br/consultanfe) (and fulfill their requirements).
2. Make your web-scraper bot solve the hCaptcha (not recommended because it's risky). There are several third-party solutions (free and paid) for it, such as [this library](https://github.com/QIN2DIM/hcaptcha-challenger) and [this paid API](https://www.capsolver.com/products/hcaptcha).